# Releasing a unique_ptr after the object is destructed

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

Is the following code legal? My worry is the use of the `.release` method after the object has been destructed in the `Start` method.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Foo ctor\n";
    }

    ~Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Foo dtor\n";
    }

    void Start()
    {
        std::unique_ptr<Foo> ptr(this);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto ptr = std::make_unique<Foo>();
    ptr->Start();
    ptr.release();
}
```

I tried this in vs12 and it didn't complain.

Comment: The perfect way to shoot out one's own leg

Comment: temporary instance within `Start()` will be destroyed when `Start()` is completed, essentially deleting `this`

Comment: Since the pointer is `release()`d immediately after, nothing especially dangerous happens, but between `ptr->Start()` completion and `ptr.release()` invocation `ptr` owns destructed object which definitely could lead to crashes and memory corruption.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got my answer. Basically, it is safe to call `release()` because although the pointed-to object is destroyed, the pointer is still a valid object on the stack.

Comment: Hopefully you won't use this technique regularly :) because the main problem with such code is its evolution. Today you remember that you must release the pointer right after `Start()`, tomorrow you forget about it, or, even worse, a different person comes to the project, and doubtlessly begins to change the code without deep understanding how it works in details. Your and his karma will become much more heavy when he finally discovers the root of crashes :)

Comment: @tcb after a pointer is `delete`d it becomes an *invalid pointer value* and using its value causes *implementation-defined behaviour* since C++14 (which may be defined as a runtime fault).   `auto p = ptr.release();` would trigger this behaviour; I'm not 100% sure if just `ptr.release()` would

Answer (score 2, accepted):

std::unique_ptr is a container for a pointer with only a single action on it: Deleting the instance it refers to when it is destroyed. (or when reset() is called)

So as long as the destructor or the reset function is not called, you'll have code which is running. However if you rewrite the Start() function to also throw an exception, you will get a crash. (Without extra catch-code) Another risk is that you are keeping a dangling pointer in your program, which you have to watch out for.

So yes, your code is legal and valid though I wouldn't recommend it as it is error-prone. I would rather recommend writing something like:

```
static void Start(std::unique_ptr<Foo> &&owner)
{
std::unique_ptr<Foo> ptr(std::move(owner));
}
```

Or if you really need ownership within this method (let's consider threads), making it a std::shared_ptr and share the ownership:

```
class Foo : std::enable_shared_from_this<Foo>
{
     void Start()
     {
     std::shared_ptr<Foo> ptr = shared_from_this();
     }
}
```